# codeigniter form_dropdown return wrong value

Tags: codeigniter

My Model,

```
function get_partners_name()
{
    $q = $this->db->select("id,fname,lname")
                      ->from('partner');
    $all_partners = $q->get()->result();
    $data = array();
    foreach($all_partners as $partner)
    {
       $data[$partner->id] = $partner->fname.' '.$partner->lname;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

my controller var_dump($partners) data is,

```
array (size=2)
  38 => string 'Mahesh' (length=6)
  40 => string 'Rahul' (length=4)
```

My view,

```
<?php array_unshift($partners, "-Select-");?>
<?php echo form_dropdown('parnter', $partners,'',''); ?>
```

so in dropdown i want to display,

```
<option value='0'>-Select-</option>
<option value='38'>Mahesh</option>
<option value='40'>Rahul</option>
```

But it display,

```
<option value='0'>-Select-</option>
<option value='1'>Mahesh</option>
<option value='2'>Rahul</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the PHP manual.

'array_unshift() prepends passed elements to the front of the array. Note that the list of elements is prepended as a whole, so that the prepended elements stay in the same order. All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero while literal keys won't be touched.'

so your keys are being renumbered when using `unshift`.

since the `select` option should never be selected I would suggest hardcoding it into the view. also don't give it a value if you don't want users to select it.

```
<select name='foo'>
    <option disabled>-Select-</option>
    <?php
    foreach($partners as $partner){
        echo '<option value="';
        echo $partner->id;
        echo '">';
        echo $partner->name;
        echo '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```